# Java fix34 codingbat

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to solve this problem on http://codingbat.com/prob/p159339

Whenever I execute the code, the nested for loop someway goes out of index, even when I indicated it to stop a value before the array.length.

Why is it not working?

Take a look at the code:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){


    int [] nums = {3,5,9,10,7,4,9,2,3,0,4,2,1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fix34(nums)));
}   
public static int[] fix34(int nums[]){
for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){

for(int k=0; i<nums.length; k++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(k);
    if(nums[i]==3 & nums[k]==4){
    int tmp;
    tmp= nums[k];
    nums[k]= nums[i+1];
    nums[i+1]=tmp;
    tmp=0;

if(k==13){
break;  
}
        }
    }



}
return nums;
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2):

Change `for(int k=0; i<nums.length; k++){` to `for(int k=0; k<nums.length; k++){`. You are using `i` for comparison. It should be `k`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
  {
  if (nums[i] == 3)
  {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < nums.length; j++)
    {
     if (nums[j] == 4 && nums[j - 1] != 3)
     {    
      int temp = nums[i+1];
      nums[i+1] = nums[j];
      nums[j] = temp;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return nums;
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score -1):

You can try this...

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {

  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
  {
    //checking for the value of 4
    if(nums[i]==4)
    {
      //looping again through the loop
      for(int j=0;j<nums.length;j++)
      {
        //checking for the value of 3
        if(nums[j]==3)
        {
          //swapping the elements
          int temp=nums[i];
          nums[i]=nums[j+1];
          nums[j+1]=temp;
          }

      }
    }
  }
  return nums;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I did it this way:

```
public int[] fix34(int[] nums) {
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 3 && i != nums.length - 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (j != 0 && nums[j] == 4 && nums[j - 1] != 3) {
                    temp = nums[i + 1];
                    nums[i + 1] = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```